# ExtJS changing the value of a combobox item on the fly

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

So im working with ExtJS 3.3, I have a combo box which im filling with values, some of the values need to be indented in the list when its expanded, so I have used `&nbsp;` this works great when the combo is expanded, but once i select an item, the `&nbsp;` actually shows in the combobox when its collapsed.

For instance; when its expanded, my values show as

```
        this is my indented value
```

and this is exactly what i want, but when collapsed, the value shows as

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;this is my indented value
```

Is there any way i can trim the spaces from the front of the value on the fly so in the expanded view it shows with the indents, but collapsed it just shows the value and nothing else?

I have found a `select` listener, but thats all i can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it the other way around, as this is easier and more logical: The indentation shouldn't be part of the value in the first place. I would modify the combo's template:

```
tpl: '<tpl for="."><div class="x-combo-list-item"><tpl if="indent">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</tpl>{text}</div></tpl>',
```

and add a boolean to the store items:

```
fields: [{
    name:'indent',
    type:'boolean'
```

which, if set to true, will indent the value corresponding to the store record.

If you want different indents, you can try to use a template function to generate your indent based on a number. The following sample only works in recent versions of ExtJS, YMMV:

```
tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for="."><div class="x-combo-list-item">{[ this.getIndent(values.indent) ]}{text}</div></tpl>', 
    {
        getIndent: function(indent) {
            var s = "";
            for(var i=0;i<indent; i++) s= s+"&nbsp;";
            return s;
        }
    }
),
store:{
    inlineData:[{
        text: 'A',
        indent:2
    },{
        text: 'B',
        indent: 4
    }],
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that as well, but i have certain amount of indents for different items, one item could have 2, another item could have 4, a root item has 2 then a subitem has 4 .. it gets quite complicated

Comment: @BigJobbies I have amended my answer.